# Can I use getCriteria to only return entries with a specified lightswitch field set to on?

Tags: plugins, elementcriteriamodel

I'm building a plugin that will check all existing entries in a section when a single entry is flagged as featured and turn off any existing featured entries. I'm using a lightswitch field to turn on and off entries. Is there a way to use the `craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);` to return just the entries with the lightswitch field turned on?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::Entry);
$criteria->section = 'mySection';
$criteria->myLightswitchField = 1;
$entries = $criteria->find();
```

Comment: Hi Brad. Is it possible to do that with a OR condition on two fields ? http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/12421/use-getcriteria-with-or-condition-on-multiple-fields

Comment: Off switch criteria is: $criteria->myLightswitchField = 'not 1';